# How to properly embed schemas into email?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, schema, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to create a sample application that will use schemas embedded into email (particulary, `ReviewAction` described in the end-to-end [example by Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/actions/end-to-end-example)).

I have created an [[image]google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) application, deployed it as described. It works as expected, excluding [gmail](/questions/tagged/gmail) doesn't add any buttons to the email.
An email is being send to the same Google account that has created the application (From and To headers of the email are the same).

What I am doing wrong in **embedding schemas into email**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReviewAction hasn't rolled out to all users yet and it is probably going to take the whole next week before it is available to test. Sorry for the delay, I'm sure you understand it takes time to roll out features to all Gmail users and to all Gmail servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Claudio. I didn't know that these features are new, and I was wondered why I'm out of luck with them.